# HTML search bar in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add a search bar to my WordPress blog. I realize that this can quickly be done with `get-search-form()`. Despite this, I am trying to achieve the result with a generic HTML search bar, as I think it looks much nicer. This is what I have in my theme:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  <span class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

How do I make this input and button act as search form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well... You're missing a search form...

```
<section class="container">
<form class="mb-3" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>" method="get">
<input name="s" type="text" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Search for kittens...">
<!--
If you want to restrict search to a specific post type...
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value=" ...Custom post type or post, page... "> -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-truncate hasrocket" type="submit"><span>Go!</span></button>
</form>
</section>
<style media="screen">
/* easter egg */
.hasrocket:hover span{display:none;}
.hasrocket:hover:before {content:"Take-off! ";}
</style>
```

Just paste that should work straight away. gl. don't hesitate if you have any more question.